# Is RPA (Robotic Process Automation) a topic for DevOps? (and so on-topic here)

Tags: discussion

It seems like that automation is possible not only through intelligent scripts but through software robots as well. They call it [robotic process automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotic_process_automation).

*Robotic process automation (or RPA) is an emerging form of clerical process automation technology based on the notion of software robots or artificial intelligence (AI) workers.*

*A software 'robot' is a software application that replicates the actions of a human being interacting with the user interface of a computer system.*

Question: do you consider questions regarding boundaries of RPA and DevOps on-topic for DevOps and so here as well?

First examples I can think of:

- How DevOps can support RPA or are these completely different domains?
- Given that DevOps toolchains are very different but represent combinations of more or less same tools, can RPA become an effective way for advanced automation in DevOps environements as well (or, why not)?

Comment: https://www.bterrell.com/robotic-process-automation-rpa/DevOps-on-their-heels

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With automation playing a major role in DevOps it is quite conceivable IMHO that RPA will eventually be involved in DevOps as well (if it doesn't do so already).

And, as you mentioned, DevOps has potential to contribute to development and evolution of RPA as well.

Therefore I'd say RPA-related questions, when in a context also related to DevOps, of course, should be on-topic to our site.

Comment: No to mention that those robots are probably software driven. This means one can use DevOps (DevOps in the course of automation) to do DevOps (Actually implementing and using the Robots).